# How to set Class-Path indict jar in the same jar

Tags: java, classloader

I want to create a Complete single Jar ball which include all of its dependencies, so it can be shipped to any one who use it from command line .

the structure of my jar is :

```
├── META-INF
│   ├── MANIFEST.MF
│   └── maven
│       └── com.cn.xing.jar
│           └── CnJar
│               ├── pom.properties
│               └── pom.xml
├── com
│   └── cn
│       └── xing
│           └── jar
│               ├── HelloJava.class
│               └── InjectEntry.class
├── lib
│   ├── aopalliance-1.0.jar
│   ├── commons-codec-1.6.jar
│   ├── commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
│   ├── gson-2.2.4.jar
│   ├── httpclient-4.3.5.jar
│   ├── httpcore-4.3.2.jar
│   ├── spring-aop-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
│   ├── spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
│   ├── spring-context-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
│   ├── spring-core-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
│   └── spring-expression-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
└── spring
    └── appCtx.xml
```

and the manifest file content is :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Built-By: ChinaXing
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_65
Class-Path: lib/spring-context-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar lib/spring-aop-3.2.2.
 RELEASE.jar lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar lib/spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.ja
 r lib/spring-core-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar lib/spring-expression-3.2.2.RELEA
 SE.jar lib/httpclient-4.3.5.jar lib/httpcore-4.3.2.jar lib/commons-lo
 gging-1.1.3.jar lib/commons-codec-1.6.jar lib/gson-2.2.4.jar
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.2.2
Main-Class: com.cn.xing.jar.InjectEntry
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
```

but when I execute it in command line as following :

```
java -jar ../CnJar-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

It show the exceptions :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2688)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2937)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1771)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 6 more
```

which means the Spring jar cannot be found .

so I want to know how to let the Jvm classLoader found the jar(s) in my jar's `lib` dir ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default Class Loader will not handle this case. You can :

1. Write classloader yourself for handle this case
2. Re-package all jars (see maven-shade-plugin, maven jarja plugin)
3. See http://one-jar.sourceforge.net

Comment: Yes, that's right. One-Jar project writes a JarClassLoader for this scenario.